# Traversing a Vertx JsonArray using RxJava

Tags: rx-java2, vert.x, vertx-verticle

I have a verticle which consumes incoming messages. Each message will be a vertx `JsonObject`, which contains a vertx `JsonArray`. I want to execute logic for each element in this array. The logic itself is contained in a separate verticle. This second verticle uses `rxVertx`. It defines several consumers, each of which delegates to separate methods, all of which return an `Observable`.

My question is: how to:

1. traverse each element in the `JsonArray`
2. pass each element to the consumer which works with `Observables`.

In the first verticle, have tried the following :

```
EventBus eb = rxVertx.eventBus();
JsonArray array= incomingMessage.getJsonArray(KEY);
List<Object> list  = array.getList();
Observable<Object> observable = Observable.fromArray(list);

observable.flatMapSingle(s -> {
      eb.rxSend(SECOND_VERTICLE_ADDRESS, s);
   }).subscribe();
```

The call to `flatMapSingle` does not compile because:

```
The method flatMapSingle(Function<? super Object,? extends SingleSource<? extends R>>) in the type Observable<Object> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> s) -> {})
```

What is the correct way to do this? Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the `flatMapSingle` function param with a code block, you must use the `return` keyword:

```
observable.flatMapSingle(s -> {
  return eb.rxSend(SECOND_VERTICLE_ADDRESS, s);
}).subscribe(reply -> {
  // Handle each reply
});
```

Note that `flatMapSingle` does not guarantee replies to be in the same order as the incoming messages. If you need that guarantee, use `concatMapSingle`.